# Dismiss two present ModalViewControllers (MPMediaPickerController and UIViewController) at the same time

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmediapickercontroller

I have a strange problem while dismissing two modalviewcontrollers.

What I am doing is I have a viewControllers A and B. I am presentingmodalviewController B on A. And then On B I am presenting `MPMediaPickerController` on B. Now my issue is After clicking on Done button in MPMediaPickerController its delegate method is calling . I have implemented the below code to dismiss the `MPMediaPickerController` and Controller B,so that We can go to Controller A directly.

```
- (void)mediaPicker:(MPMediaPickerController *)mediaPicker didPickMediaItems: (MPMediaItemCollection *) mediaItemCollection
{  
    [self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Same code is working for ViewControllers A, B and C but not working if third one is `MPMediaPickerController`

Any ideas or suggestions are very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you present MPMediaPickerController from a controller then you have to set its delegate to the presenting controller. So as because delegate method is inside the presenting view controller, you have to call dismissModalViewControllerAnimated instead of whatever you are doing. I am just passing bool parameter to NO because whenever you will try to dismiss more then one viewcontroller simultaneously at that time there will be unbalanced transition call by the iOS and that may prevent another call. So i just dismissed MPMediaPickerController without any animation and the presenting view controller with animation.

```
- (void)mediaPicker:(MPMediaPickerController *)mediaPicker didPickMediaItems: (MPMediaItemCollection *) mediaItemCollection
{  
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    [self.presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: When answering questions it's a good idea to explain the code you post.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated` method ? It is deprecated, use `dismissViewControllerAnimated` instead.

Check with this code:

```
- (void)mediaPicker:(MPMediaPickerController *)mediaPicker didPickMediaItems: (MPMediaItemCollection *) mediaItemCollection
{ 
   [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        [[self presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried the below codes?

```
- (void)mediaPicker:(MPMediaPickerController *)mediaPicker didPickMediaItems: (MPMediaItemCollection *) mediaItemCollection
{  
    [mediaPicker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; 

}
```

Thanks!